# Detection of data type through scanf + usage of it in further functions

Tags: c

So I'm relatively new to C and am trying out some beginner programs. One of which is a program that reads user input from stdin (through usage of scanf).

I'm gonna explain everything step by step for sake of easier comprehension of my intentions (although this part of code is functional/operational and does not require any specific help. So if you wish, you may skip straight to the question below)

So we have a program that reads input from scanf() and decides if it's number or string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isNumber(const char *input){
 /* while not end of string */
 while (*input != '\0'){
/* if we do not detect a number, return 0 */
  if (*input < '0' || '9' < *input)
   return 0;
 input++;
  }
return 1;
}

int main(void){
char uInput[30];

/*Ask user for input */
printf("Please enter number or word \n");
scanf("%29s", uInput);

if (isNumber(uInput)){
 printf("We found a number %s \n", uInput);
}

else {
 printf("We found a word %s \n", uInput);
}

return 0;
}
```

So yeah, in the program so works so far. Hopefully everything's clear. Now I know this is not the optimal way of the detection, but that's currently not of concern.

**Question begins from here:**

Now I've decided to spice things up a little, by adding another function.
To be more specific, it's concerning about prime numbers.

So I've began with the function of

```
int prime(int number){
 int divider;

 for (divider = 2; divider <= number - 1; divider++){

  if (number%divider == 0)
  return 0;


  else if (number == divider)
  return 1;
 }
}
```

Under presumption everything in my function is correct, I decided to initialize the function in my main() function.

Basically what I want to do:

if the user input is a word - print out the word
if the user input is a number - check if the number is prime and then print out the number and whether it's prime.

So here's how I change up the code:

```
int main (void){
 char uInput[30];
 int result;


 /*User input goes here*/
 printf("Please enter a number or a word \n");
 scanf("%29s", uInput);

/* if it contains any numbers do */
if(isNumber(uInput)){
result = prime(uInput);

  /* now I've created another if condition, if it is a prime number */
  if(result == 1){
   printf("It is a prime number: %d \n", uInput);
  } else {
   printf("It is a number: %d \n", uInput);

}
else {
printf("It is a word %s \n", uInput);
}

return 0;
}
```

Suspicion: Now I'm 99% sure there is an error in this code (and not just a syntax one). I probably even know where it lies, but due to my lack of knowledge I'm not really sure how to fix it.

So as I was doing the function for the prime number, I wasn't certain if I should make it as a result of string or an integer. Issue is, my program runs through the word as a string and even if it is a number, technically it remains a string under 'illusion that it's a number'.

Issue was, I'm not really sure how would I compare a prime number, that's not an integer but a string. So I've changed %s to %d on my printf. I assume there must be some form of conversion, that I'm not aware of.

But was of no succes. Currently, the word detection works, but when I input for example 2, my output results in

> "I input 2 into scanf() through console"
>
> > It is a number 2686752

Desired result would be

> > It is a prime number: 2

(Which also means by deduction, it doesn't even use the first if and skips to else, because if it would have been a prime number the printf for it is different. So there may be something wrong with my "prime" function as well.

So issue is, I can't use scanf(%d, uInput) because otherwise the string detection wouldn't work and clearly my solution is not correct either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't increment a `const char *` pointer.

Comment: @cpp_prog yes you can, you can't change what it points to though. `const char *` means 'pointer to constant character'. You're thinking of `char * const`, which means 'constant pointer to character'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a problem in your `prime` function. Check for `(number == divider)` is incorrect. You can simply remove the `else if` part as below.

```
int prime(int number){
 int divider;

 for (divider = 2; divider <= number - 1; divider++){
  if (number%divider == 0)
   return 0;
 }
 return 1;
}
```

Next issue is in the way you get a number from `uInput`. You can use `atoi` for this as below

```
if(isNumber(uInput)){
result = prime(atoi(uInput));

  /* now I've created another if condition, if it is a prime number */
  if(result == 1){
   printf("It is a prime number: %s \n", uInput);
  } else {
   printf("It is a number: %s \n", uInput);

}
else {
printf("It is a word %s \n", uInput);
}
```

Complete code is as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isNumber(const char *input){
 /* while not end of string */
 while (*input != '\0'){
/* if we do not detect a number, return 0 */
  if (*input < '0' || '9' < *input)
   return 0;
 input++;
  }
return 1;
}

int prime(int number){
 int divider;

 for (divider = 2; divider <= number - 1; divider++){

  if (number%divider == 0)
  return 0;
 }

 return 1;
}

int main (void){
 char uInput[30];
 int result;


 /*User input goes here*/
 printf("Please enter a number or a word \n");
 scanf("%29s", uInput);

/* if it contains any numbers do */
if(isNumber(uInput)){
result = prime(atoi(uInput));

  /* now I've created another if condition, if it is a prime number */
  if(result == 1){
   printf("It is a prime number: %s \n", uInput);
  } else {
   printf("It is a number: %s \n", uInput);

  }
}
else {
printf("It is a word %s \n", uInput);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey there! May I bother you for couple more minutes please? Could you please elaborate (in some simplistic way) why (number == divider) was incorrect? My mind's a blank and I don't want to just mindlessly copy-paste code, but actually learn where my mistakes lie.Regardless though, thanks a lot, greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: `divider` can never be equal to `number` inside the loop. Loop exits when the `divider` is incremented to the value `number` as it does not satisfy the condition `divider <= number - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a number with [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

In your `main`, after determining the input is a number, convert it to an `int` and pass that to `prime`:

```
...
/* if it contains any numbers do */
if(isNumber(uInput)){
    int iInput = atoi(uInput);
    result = prime(iInput);

    /* now I've created another if condition, if it is a prime number */
...
```

Then you can either print the number with `%d`:

```
printf("It is a prime number: %d \n", iInput); /* note: iInput */
```

or with `%s`:

```
printf("It is a prime number: %s \n", uInput); /* note: uInput */
```

Comment: That solves the issue of my values. Unfortunately the detection problem stands. It currently prints "It is a number: (number)" regardless whether it's prime or not.

Not sure if you have any suggestions for that, thanks though regardless.

Comment: @Rawrplus: This answer should work _Under presumption everything in my function is correct_.

Comment: @mouviciel well as I turned out my presumption was incorrect. Regardless though, the solution to both has been provided in highlighted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first get the line with `fgets`, and then scan it with `sscanf`:

```
char line[80], word[32];
int num;

if (fgets(line, 79, stdin)) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%31s", word) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", word);                      // it's a string
    else if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num) == 1)        // it's a number
        printf("%d: %s\n", num, (isprime(num)) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime");
}

char *isprime(int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i < n - 1; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```